# Some logs lost when writing from multi-threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm writing a multi-threaded system using c++. I defined a log object as global variable, and all threads write logs into this object.

Log class is defined as follow.

log.h

```
#ifndef LOG_H_
#define LOG_H_

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <mutex>

enum class LogType{
    ERROR,
    WARNING,
    INFO,
    DEBUG
};

class ContentsCopyLog
{
public:
    bool open(std::string logFile);
    void write(LogType type, std::string msg);
    void close();
private:
    std::fstream f_;
    std::mutex mtx_;
};

#endif
```

log.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "log.h"

bool ContentsCopyLog::open(std::string logFile)
{
    f_.open(logFile, std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
    if(!f_.is_open()){
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

void ContentsCopyLog::write(LogType type, std::string msg)
{
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::time_t current_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtx_);
    char buf[100];
    strftime(buf, 100, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S ", localtime(&current_time));

    f_ << buf;

    if(type == LogType::ERROR){
        f_ << "[ERROR  ] ";
    }else if(type == LogType::WARNING){
        f_ << "[WARNING] ";
    }else if(type == LogType::INFO){
        f_ << "[INFO   ] ";
    }else if(type == LogType::DEBUG){
        f_ << "[DEBUG  ] ";
    }
    f_ << msg << std::endl;
}

void ContentsCopyLog::close()
{
    if(f_.is_open()){
        f_.close();
    }
}
```

All worker threads execute the same function. In this function some logs will be written into the log file.

The problem now is it seems logs from some threads have not been written into the log file.
Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure that all writes are complete before closing?  Also, are you positive that you aren't getting write errors to disk and ignoring with your << call?

Comment: mtx_ is defined as a member variable of Log class.  There is only one Log object defined in the whole program, as a global variable.

Comment: yeah - caught that and edited the comment.  Sorry for that.  The question about how you close is still open though as is potential write errors not being caught.

Comment: Try flushing the file buffer.

Comment: You are right. As the program is running as daemon, the log file did not properly closed. I added f_,flush() at the end of the function and it seems OK now. Thanks.